# parsing line of input c++

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I'm writing a program the do the Depth-first-search. Yes this is homework, but the part I'm having issues with is not the learning point of the assignment. I am being given badly formatted input and am having trouble separating the input into valid variables and storing them. When I say badly formatted data I mean there is not a specific number of spaces between valid data and the # of variables per line is not consistent... trying to find a more elegant way of getting the data I need instead of a nest of 3 loops. Any help is greatly appreciated.
My current code:

```
int main()
{
    //read in first line (# of lines WITH data)
    cout << "enter the number of lines\n";
    cin >> lines;

    //if non integer entered it won't error now
    while(!cin)
    {
        cin.clear(); // clears the error flags
        cin.ignore(20, '\n'); //flush the buffer
        cout <<"\ndid not enter a valid integer, please try again\n\n";
        //reprompt for VALID input
        cout << "enter the number of lines\n";
        cin >> lines;
    }
    //lines should now have a valid int input value

    //eat blank line
    getline(cin,str);


    //read in (# of lines WITH data retrieved from first input)
    for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, str);// read first string
        //process str
        //while not end of line
        //{
    
        //breakup line into individual variables
        std::string delim = " "; //set space as a delimiter
        size_t pos = 0;
        string token;
        while ((pos = str.find(delim)) != std::string::npos)
        {
            token = str.substr(0,pos);
            //set token to variable that increases (array location?)

            //get char, loop to check if chare = " ", eat it if it is until its not

        }
        //}

        //place variables in array location
        //...
    }
    //eat blank line at end of data set
    getline(cin,str);

    //alphabetize array
    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

sample input:

```
11

Harry       Kate(18)       Fred(5)        Carol(6)
Alice      James(25)       Daisy(21)      Kate(10)
Carol     Fred(2)         Harry(6)       Daisy(12)
Ivy        James(16)       Bob(24)
Daisy       Carol(12)     Alice(21)     Elvis(28)
Elvis        James(18)       Daisy(28)      Fred(29)
Kate       Alice(10)      Fred(14)       Harry(18)    Gerald(20)
Fred        Kate(14)       Carol(2)     Harry(5)     Elvis(29)
Gerald      Kate(20)       Bob(17)    James(10)
James       Gerald(10)      Elvis(18)       Alice(25)   Ivy(16)
Bob     Ivy(24)        Gerald(17)
```

Comment: What is the data? string or int or ???

Comment: `operator>>` will skip all leading whitespace (including newlines) for you, you only need to concentrate on whether the values are correct or not.

Comment: You want to use a `std::istringstream` initialized from the current line.

Comment: Why not give us a representative section of actual input to cross-reference with your code?

Comment: actual sample input:
11

Harry       Kate(18)       Fred(5)        Carol(6)
Alice      James(25)       Daisy(21)      Kate(10)
Carol     Fred(2)         Harry(6)       Daisy(12)
Ivy        James(16)       Bob(24)
Daisy       Carol(12)     Alice(21)     Elvis(28)
Elvis        James(18)       Daisy(28)      Fred(29)
Kate       Alice(10)      Fred(14)       Harry(18)    Gerald(20)
Fred        Kate(14)       Carol(2)     Harry(5)     Elvis(29)
Gerald      Kate(20)       Bob(17)    James(10)
James       Gerald(10)      Elvis(18)       Alice(25)   Ivy(16)
Bob     Ivy(24)        Gerald(17)

Comment: i can't get it to be formatted the way the file actually is. example the 1st input is the number of lines, then a blank line, then 3 lines with 4 variables, 1 line with 3 variables, 2 lines with 4 variables, 2 lines with 5 variables, etc.... and ya the spaces between them vary

Comment: What does the number in parenthesis mean?

Comment: the number is not used in this assignment, and will need to be chopped out along with the "(" and ")"

Comment: was able to get it done by:
    for (istringstream linestream(str); linestream >> word;)
  {
   //"word" contains individual words from 
                        //store word where desired
                }

Answer (score 1):

You can tokenize each line with std::istringstream and std::istream_iterator. A sample code is given below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> parse_line(const std::string& s) {
  std::vector<T> result;
  std::istringstream iss(s);
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<T>(iss), std::istream_iterator<T>(),
            std::back_inserter(result));
  return result;
}

int main() {
  std::string s{"Harry       Kate(18)       Fred(5)        Carol(6)"};
  auto r = parse_line<std::string>(s);
  for (auto const& e : r) std::cout << e << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should give Boost a try, for each line:

```
string myline = "Harry       Kate(18)       Fred(5)";
vector<string> result;
boost::split(result, myline, boost::is_any_of(" "));
```

Then result will contain for example:

```
 result[0] = Harry
 result[1] = Kate(18)
 result[2] = Fred(5)
 etc...
```

Then you need to iterate through this vector, I suggest you use `regex` to see if each string contains parenthesis. Then you can get name and numbers.

Comment: i'm only allowed to use strings and arrays :/  but what you have there looks like a great way to accomplish what i'm after and regex sounds very interesting. (i posted a way i found how to separate the words from the line, wouldn't let me post my own answer since i'm a newb to the site). is there a way to parse out the "(#)" that doesn't involve vectors?

Comment: Not much time to answer but you must know that `regex` is used on strings. If you have all your words stored somewhere (array or else), you can check if each has numbers in it with that regex for example: `[0-9]{1,2}`. If something matches, you will be able to get it back.